# Lipschitz continuous mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Given a twice Lipschitz continuously differentiable mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, and any $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we want to bound the following formula
$$
\|(f(x)-2f(y) +f(z) \| = \|(f(x)-f(y)) - (f(y)-f(z))   \|.
$$
In particular, we wish that
$$
\| (f(x)-2f(y) +f(z)  \| \leq \sigma \max\{\|x-y\|^2, \|y-z\|^2, \|x-z\|^2  \},
$$
where $\sigma$ is a constant. How to verify the above inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m=n$ and $f(x)=x$ and suppose that

$$\| (f(x)-2f(y) +f(z)  \| \leq \sigma \max\{\|x-y\|^2, \|y-z\|^2, \|x-z\|^2  \}$$

holds for all $x,y,z.$

With $z=0$ and $x=y$ we get

$$\|x \| \le  \sigma \|x\|^2$$

for all $x$. But this is a contradiction !